# Add CDept_Id In first query for result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

In my first query, I want to get `CDept_Id`. But `CDept_Id` column does not exist in `inward_doc_tracking_hdr` table.

It comes from `inward_doc_tracking_trl` table. like below

```
SELECT  CDept_id
FROM    inward_doc_tracking_trl
WHERE   ref_mkey IN ( SELECT    mkey
                      FROM      inward_doc_tracking_hdr
                      WHERE     doc_no = 'IW/HU/16/42' )
```

So, From this. I get `CDept_Id`. Now I want to add this in my below query.

```
SELECT  mkey ,
        Delivered_By ,
        Department_Id ,
        ( SELECT    mkey
          FROM      erp190516.dbo.emp_mst
          WHERE     mkey IN ( SELECT    employee_mkey
                              FROM      erp190516.dbo.user_mst
                              WHERE     mkey = To_User )
        ) User_Id ,
        Doc_Type ,
        Email_Id ,
        Ref_No ,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), Ref_date, 103) Ref_date ,
        Inward_Amt ,
        Remarks ,
        party_name ,
        disp_through
FROM    erp190516.dbo.inward_doc_tracking_hdr ,
        CDept_id  -- add CDept_id here
WHERE   doc_no = 'IW/HU/16/42'
        AND Status_Flag = '13'
```

How to add this

**UPDATE**

`inward_doc_tracking_hdr` mkey is equal to `inward_doc_tracking_trl` ref_mkey

Comment: Please provide table structure so that we can understand table relation and provide you the more better solutions than existing one.

Comment: @Suraz: I want to add `CDept_Id` column in my second query. What help you need related to this ?

Comment: Its clear after formatting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is reading the magic glass bulb, but I think you might nead an `INNER JOIN` to the other table using the `mkey` and `ref_mkey` as link:

```
Select hdr.mkey
      ,hdr.Delivered_By
      ,hdr.Department_Id 
      ,hdr.Doc_Type,Email_Id
      ,hdr.Ref_No
      ,convert(varchar(25),hdr.Ref_date,103) Ref_date
      ,hdr.Inward_Amt
      ,hdr.Remarks
      ,hdr.party_name
      ,hdr.disp_through
      ,trl.CDept_Id
from erp190516.dbo.inward_doc_tracking_hdr AS hdr
inner join erp190516.dbo.inward_doc_tracking_trl AS trl on hdr.mkey=trl.ref_mkey
 where hdr.doc_no = 'IW/HU/16/42'  
 and hdr.Status_Flag = '13'
```

### UPDATE ...even more guessing...

--First CTE to get the partioned order of CDept_Id

```
;WITH OrderedCDept AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ref_mkey ORDER BY CDept_Id DESC) AS SortInx
          ,ref_mkey
          ,CDept_Id
    FROM erp190516.dbo.inward_doc_tracking_trl
)
```

--Second CTE to use `TOP 1 WITH TIES` to fetch all *first* rows

```
,LatestCDept AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
    FROM OrderedCDept
    ORDER BY SortInx
)
```

--Now use the second CTE instead of the table to join

```
Select hdr.mkey
      ,hdr.Delivered_By
      ,hdr.Department_Id 
      ,hdr.Doc_Type,Email_Id
      ,hdr.Ref_No
      ,convert(varchar(25),hdr.Ref_date,103) Ref_date
      ,hdr.Inward_Amt
      ,hdr.Remarks
      ,hdr.party_name
      ,hdr.disp_through
      ,trl.CDept_Id
from erp190516.dbo.inward_doc_tracking_hdr AS hdr
inner join LatestCDept AS trl on hdr.mkey=trl.ref_mkey
 where hdr.doc_no = 'IW/HU/16/42'  
 and hdr.Status_Flag = '13'
```

Comment: my `CDept_Id` is giving me more than one value how to get the latest one ?? I mean in the `desc` format